# postgresql select query with variables

Tags: php, postgresql

I am trying to make a postgresql select query work with php, but can't get past the syntax.

I have a variable and a query that returns the surname of any match.

```
$name = 'Smith';
$query = 'SELECT surname FROM emploee WHERE name= '.$name.';';
$a = pg_query(connect(),$query );
while($row = pg_fetch_array($a)){ echo "Match";    }
```

For those who wonder why do I have to declare Smith as a variable, `$name` is not always equals to Smith. The value of `$name` is taken **correctly** from another query. However, this is not working. I read in an article that I should use pg_query_params() but couldn't get that to work neither.

Your help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Are you sure you have database connection? And for pg_queruy_params() you need a SQL-placeholder like $1 in your SQL-statement.

Comment: I am sure I do. I have established it earlier but didn't include it in the post. Also, the value I get for $name is taken in another query that uses that connection, so it works. As for pg_query_params() I read the php manual and saw the example, but wasn't able to adapt it to my case. The problem is on including a variable in the query (quote issues). I just dont know how to make it right.

Comment: Do check number of rows returned before using while

Comment: @parveen: Although it is a good point, the inner design of the actual code makes it impossible for more than 1 row to return. And anyway, the number of Match strings is a way to check. But you obviously couldn't notice this in the piece of code that I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the two methods that worked, suggested by Bang and Frank Heikens respectively. Since they only commented, I am posting it as an answer for those who might come up the same situation. However, I would strongly advise them to read the comments too. I learned a couple of stuff on the way, you might as well.

Bang's suggestions->

```
$a = trim($name); 
$query = "SELECT surname FROM employee WHERE name= '" . $a . "';"; 
$result = pg_query(connect(), $query); 
while($row = pg_fetch_array($result)){ echo "Match"; }
```

Frank Heikens suggestions ->

```
$n = trim($name);
$s = trim($surname);
$params = array ($n, $s);
$result = pg_query_params(connect(), 'SELECT office FROM emploee WHERE name = $1 and surname = $2', $params);
while($row = pg_fetch_array($result)){ $k = $row['path']." ".$row['office'];  echo $k; }
```

In both cases I have to use trim (not sure if this will be your case too). I added a third field **office** to demonstrate how can I take several arguments. 
If anyone has other critics, suggestions or solutions, be my guest. I will try everyone of them and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$query = "SELECT surname FROM emploee WHERE name= '" . $name . "';";
```

And the best way without binding :

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT surname FROM emploee WHERE name = '%s'", pg_escape_string($name));
```

And if you want to use binding :

```
$result = pg_query_params(connect(), 'SELECT surname FROM emploee WHERE name = $1', array($name));
```

As you get a result from other query ' Smith', there is a white space.

To remove white space from `$name`, you can do : `$name = trim($name);`

Comment: This is the error I get with the first try:                                                                                                  Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: column " Smith" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT surname FROM emploee WHERE name= " John"; ^ in //file_path                                                                                                                    With the second statement I get this error :                                                            pg_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in

Comment: I have change " to ', your query should look like SELECT surname FROM emploee WHERE name= 'John';

Comment: Don't use pg_query without any protection against SQL injection! If you really don't want to use pg_query_params(), you must use pg_escape_string() for your input.

Comment: @Bang:  Thanks a lot! Both alternatives work, in the way I posed the question. I would love to accept your question. However, in my original code (as I mentioned earlier in the post) I dont assign the values of $name manually. I get them from another query. So unless I assign the value as $name = 'Smith'; it wont work. My bad that i simplified the question in such a manner.

Comment: @ Frank Heikens: You are right. But right now I am not thinking of security. I am trying to make it function in the first stage and then I will add the security measures. Thanks for the reminder though

Comment: If you don't work secure now, your code will be insecure forever.... You would be the first who would make code secure afterwards. Security is not an add on, it's a way of coding. And you need just 3 changes to make it safe: use pg_query_params(), use placeholders in your SQL and create an array to use in pg_query_params(). It only takes a minute!

Comment: @amygrimaldi: So in your case can you dump your $name content by using var_dump and show the raised error ?

Comment: @Frank Heikens : string(6) " Smith"  is what I get if I do var_dump.

Comment: look, you have a space. You can use trim() to prevent getting space in the begin and end of your string. try trim($name)

Comment: @Bang: It worked when I used trim(). i had completely missed the space there... Would you mind to remove it from comment and post it as an answer?

Comment: @Frank Heikens: Pardon my ignorance, I am not familiar with placeholders and only read about pg_query_params() a few hours ago. But I will take your advice in consideration and try to make it work that way. php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php is the link I am consulting. However, I am not getting it 100%. I would appreciate it if you post some example or link. Because, I dont have an array of variables, like in that example that uses implode() in the link. And when i try to adapt it I get errors. Either way, thanks for the advice given up to now

Comment: This is after Bang's comments and works. However, as soon as I find away to do it after Frank Heikens suggestions, I will post that too, since he has a very good point when he talks about secure coding.                                                                        $a = trim($name);
$query = "SELECT surname FROM employee WHERE name= '" . $a . "';";                                                                                                      $result = pg_query(connect(), $query);                                               while($row = pg_fetch_array($result)){ echo "Match"; }

Comment: Never use that first query.  It introduces errors and security problems.  Also,  sometimes names have apostrophes.

Answer (score 0):

With this code above: you can print "match" for each record matched with query

```
$a = trim($name); 
$query = "SELECT surname FROM employee WHERE name= '" . $a . "';"; 
$result = pg_query(connect(), $query); 
while($row = pg_fetch_array($result)){ echo "Match"; }
```

But certainly you need to print the values returned:
just make it echo `$row['columnName']`

Full details here:https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/select.php